# Wordpress Permalink changes to question mark (?) in URL

Tags: permalinks, customization, urls

My Permalink custom url is /%post_id%/%postname%/

and my website is in Persian language, for some posts the Permalink is change in URL from

[http://www.ahangbaz.com/1300/%d8%a7%d8%a8%db%8c-%d8%b7%d9%be%d8%b4-%da%86%d8%b4%d9%85%d9%87/](http://www.ahangbaz.com/1300/%D8%A7%D8%A8%DB%8C-%D8%B7%D9%BE%D8%B4-%DA%86%D8%B4%D9%85%D9%87/)
 into --> 
http://www.ahangbaz.com/1300/?-???-????/

but this doesn't happen for all post, for e.g following post works fine:
ahangbaz.com/1106/%D9%82%DB%8C%D8%B5%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D8%B9%D8%AF-%DA%86%D9%86%D8%AF-%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%84/

I checked in wp_posts table of wordpress and Post_name seems similar for both posts.

If I change the post_name to English it works fine but when post_name is in Persian,problem occures. web server is IIS 7.5 on windows 2008 R2.

---

Further tests:

- I changed the thema and disabled all plugin, it still happens. I checked DB colation and its UTF8.
- To reproduce the issue use the post_title = ابی - طپش - چشمه and post_name will be  %d8%a7%d8%a8%db%8c-%d8%b7%d9%be%d8%b4-%da%86%d8%b4%d9%85%d9%87
- The same problem happens with categories when the slug is in Persian ahangbaz.com/category/%d8%a7%d8%a8%db%8c doesn't work but when its in English or a number it works ahangbaz.com/category/22.

Comment: Hm, I get `/368/ابی-ستاره-دنباله-دار-ستاره-دنباله-دار/` as URL for this in my installation (Apache server). Maybe a server issue.

Comment: Do you have IIS 7.5 environment to reproduce ? it works for some posts like http://www.ahangbaz.com/1106/%D9%82%DB%8C%D8%B5%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D8%B9%D8%AF-%DA%86%D9%86%D8%AF-%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%84/

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no IIS 7.5 at hand. Maybe someone else can make further tests. I moved your further information from the comments to the question body to make it easier to read.

Comment: in fiddler i can see that GET http://www.ahangbaz.com/1300/%d8%a7%d8%a8%db%8c-%d8%b7%d9%be%d8%b4-%da%86%d8%b4%d9%85%d9%87/ HTTP/1.1 ----->>>> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://www.ahangbaz.com/1300/?-???-????/
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5

Comment: I find the reason: this happens only when column wp_posts.post_name containts %d8%a8%db%8c which is in persian بی , so by removing %d8%a8%db%8c from post_name it works. maybe mysql has problem in finding this collation.

Comment: I don't think this is a DB problem. Looks more like URL handling in either the server or PHP.

Comment: As you said probably php is not passing to mysql the correct encoding, I changed also in php.ini default_charset = "utf-8" but didnt solve it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem as @Indolering mentioned is related to URL Rewrite module that the URLs containing UTF-8 characters is not correctly passed when processed by the URL Rewrite module.

Because I'm not the server owner and I'm unable to install the mentioned hotfix (even though I'm using IIS8.5 the problem is still existed) I had to get around this in somehow.

[The solution suggested by @pouria-p](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25592621/893350) for Joomla is also applicable to Wordpress.

**Step 1.**
Update the rewrite rule in the `web.config` file

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="WordPress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>

                    <!-- The changes are applied to this line only -->
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The rule will be as following :

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?requesturi={URL}" />
```

**Step 2.** Update the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` manually by adding the following line to the top of the `index.php` file :

```
if(isset($_GET['requesturi']))
  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_GET['requesturi'];
```

Comment: This workaround is also applicable for using free version of Polylang plugin. The plugin uses posts and pages' name in URL and IIS share hosting routes it like ***site.com/mm/?????*** .

Comment: You solution is partly correct. If we put those 2 lines in index.php file by updating of  WordPress it will be gone. So I suggest to put `if(isset($_GET['requesturi']))  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_GET['requesturi'];` inside the `functions.php` of your *child theme*. It means you have to create a child theme if you don't have and put these 2 lines at the beginning of that file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have comment capabilities, but the problem is very likely to be on the MS server side, specifically the URL Rewrite module.  This is what handles permalinks on IIS.  There is a [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2277918) for this problem, but you should probably apply all the hotfixes available for your system.

Comment: Well, IMO, this is much more an Answer than a Comment. But adding a summary from the external link would improve greatly the quality of the answer.